# How to display data from firebase in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

My current code gets and displays data from `firebase` database when it is running as an application but does not display anything in `flutter` web.

```
 class News extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewsState createState() => _NewsState();
}

class _NewsState extends State<News> {
  List<Posts> postsList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    DatabaseReference postsRef =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Posts");
postsRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
  var keys = snapshot.value.keys;
  var data = snapshot.value;

  postsList.clear();

  for (var individualKey in keys) {
    Posts posts = new Posts(
      data[individualKey]['postImage'],
      data[individualKey]['title'],
      data[individualKey]['date'],
      data[individualKey]['time'],
      data[individualKey]['description'],
    );

    postsList.add(posts);
  }

  setState(() {
    print('Length: $postsList.length');
  });
});
```

}

This is my code to get the data from the firebase database, it works perfectly fine (shows output) when I run it as a mobile application but does not work when I run it in a web browser.

Comment: Could you provide more information?

Comment: Can you post the whole code ?